# Pb with Row selection on a time-series index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

With this toy data::

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(2, 9, size=(8, 3)))
df.index = pd.date_range(start='2015-04', periods=8, freq='Q')
df
#             0  1  2
# 2015-06-30  7  5  5
# 2015-09-30  5  5  8
# 2015-12-31  2  4  3
# 2016-03-31  2  5  8
# 2016-06-30  2  2  3
# 2016-09-30  6  6  6
# 2016-12-31  8  5  3
# 2017-03-31  8  2  2
```

This work well, we can filter on a specific month::

```
df.loc[df.index.month == 9, :]
#             0  1  2
# 2015-09-30  5  5  8
# 2016-09-30  6  6  6
```

But how make an "isin" filter if we need to take values from a list ?::

```
df.loc[df.index.month in [6, 12], :]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-577-49bc5540b6dd> in <module>()
# ----> 1 df.loc[df.index.month in [6, 12], :]
# 
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.in1d()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) to test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array.

```
In [32]: df.loc[np.in1d(df.index.month, [6, 12]), :]
Out[32]:
            0  1  2
2015-06-30  8  6  4
2015-12-31  2  3  4
2016-06-30  8  7  3
2016-12-31  4  7  3
```

However, if you want to use 'isin()' method only, you could, convert `df.index.month` to series and check `isin([6, 12])` condition

```
In [34]: df.loc[pd.Series(df.index.month).isin([6, 12]).values, :]
Out[34]:
            0  1  2
2015-06-30  8  6  4
2015-12-31  2  3  4
2016-06-30  8  7  3
2016-12-31  4  7  3
```

Alternatively, you can also

```
In [33]: df.loc[[x in [6, 12] for x in df.index.month], :]
Out[33]:
            0  1  2
2015-06-30  8  6  4
2015-12-31  2  3  4
2016-06-30  8  7  3
2016-12-31  4  7  3
```